# exit during long sleep

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the easiest way to exit this `while` loop while it's still sleeping?
Is there some kind of function that can detect if a value is true while sleeping?
Or do I set up a small sleep in a loop and check to exit if not sleep some more? if so how would I do that?

```
        std::atomic<bool> _execute;

        while (_execute.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) 
        {
            //do stuff

            //How to exit druing this long sleep
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minutes(_Delay));
        }
```

Comment: So what's `_execute.load(std::memory_order_acquire)` doing exactly? Respectively what's the type of `_execute`?

Comment: It dont matter what its doing, im trying to exit the sleep, `std::atomic<bool> _execute;`

Answer (score 11):

> Is there some kind of function that can detect if a value is true while sleeping?

No there isn't such method to break out a `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` call within the same thread. The thread is suspended for more or less the time specified in the `std::chrono::duration` argument.

> Whats the easiest way to exit this While loop while its still sleeping?
>   Or do I set up a small sleep in a loop and check to exit if not sleep some  more? if so how would I do that?

Do not let it sleep (that long) at all.

Instead of the `sleep_for()` You can use a condition variable and [`wait_for()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for) for signalling to exit the loop (from another thread).

---

As you have clarified that in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658000/exit-during-long-sleep/35658198#comment58997857_35658000), instead of using the `std::atomic<bool>` you should reorganize your code a bit (again using a condition variable):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

const std::chrono::seconds  MainDelay = std::chrono::seconds(5);
const std::chrono::seconds  WorkerTimeResolution = std::chrono::seconds(2);
std::mutex cv_m;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool _execute = false;

void worker_thread() {
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
   while (cv.wait_for(lk,WorkerTimeResolution,[](){return _execute ;})) {
        // do stuff as long _execute is true, 
        // may be with more varying timing conditions than sleep_for() ...
        std::cout << "Worker thread executing ..." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(WorkerTimeResolution);
   }     
}

int main() {
    std::thread t(worker_thread);
    _execute = true;
    cv.notify_all();

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        // Do other stuff, may be with more varying timing conditions ...
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(MainDelay);
        std::cout << "Main thread executing ..." << std::endl;
    }
    _execute = false;
    cv.notify_all();
    t.join();
}
```

[<kbd>Online Demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/iXREqg)

---

Note that there are a number of possible operations rather than `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`, that might be synchronized in

```
// Do stuff ...
```

and cause the current thread being suspended.

Comment: +1 for `wait_unitl()`; [condition variables](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/) (was helping me to get an overview).

Answer (score 3):

You wrote your code to literally do nothing for *x* minutes; now you instead want it to do things (check a condition) during that time. You can't have it both ways!

Replace your `sleep` with a wait on a *condition variable*.

Comment: _execute.load(std::memory_order_acquire) is the condition, clearly this is not my code this is a example on what i want to do.

Comment: This sounds rather like a design problem in your code.

Comment: @ramafe So you posted a question that is different than your code?  No, that isn't clear.